# Check body load (or other element)

Tags: jquery

I want to show my div (wrapper) when body is loaded. This is my code:

```
$("div.wrapper").hide();
$('body').load(function() {
    $('.wrapper').show();
});
```

But my code not work. What is my mistake?

Comment: Bodies don't "load". Bodies _rock_.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Description

> **.ready()** Specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully loaded.

So make your div invisible using `css` and make it visible using `jQuery`.

#### Sample

**Html**

```
<div class="wrapper" style="display:none">
   <!-- your content -->
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.wrapper').show();
});
```

**Complete Sample**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="PathToYourJqueryJsFile" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.wrapper').show();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper" style="display:none">
        <!-- your content -->
        </div>  
    </body>
</html>
```

#### More Information

- [jQuery.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)
- [jQuery.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/)

Comment: Heh, I never saw such a comprehensive answer about "use `$(document).ready`"

Answer (score 3):

First, set  `.wrapper {display:none}` in your css file.  Then, this code should show it after the page has loaded:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.wrapper').show();
});
```

Comment: I think the problem might be `$('body').load`  instead of `$(document).load`

Answer (score 0):

1. you use jquery,do you load jquery right? check in the console what happens when you write $ and hit Enter.
2. all jQuery code should be called from inside

   $(document).ready(function(){ //your function});

**edit**: this is the same as $(function(){}); style but I prefer the more verbose style

Answer (score 0):

use jquery and simply do

```
<script>
    $(function(){ //jquery short-hand for DOM ready!!!
        $('.wrapper').show(function(){ 
             console.log('I AM SHOWING!!');
        });
    });
</script>
```